# Можно ли присвоить переменной результат запроса?SQL,TRANSACT-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Делаю запрос на получение int значения.Можно ли присвоить переменной резултат этого запроса?

```
declare @enddate int;
SET @enddate = SELECT dbo.Date_Dim.ID FROM dbo.Date_Dim WHERE dbo.Date_Dim.DateOper = '2013-06-27';
```

Такая конструкция не работает.Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно это делается так:

```
SELECT @enddate = dbo.Date_Dim.ID 
                FROM dbo.Date_Dim 
                WHERE dbo.Date_Dim.DateOper = '2013-06-27');
```

При этом одним запросом можно присвоить значения нескольким переменным:

```
select @i1 = i1, @i2 = i2, ... from ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Запрос нужно обернуть в скобки. То есть

```
DECLARE @enddate INT;
SET @enddate = (SELECT dbo.Date_Dim.ID 
                FROM dbo.Date_Dim 
                WHERE dbo.Date_Dim.DateOper = '2013-06-27');
```

ну и позаботиться о том, чтобы он возвращал только одно значение, если это не так

Comment: да,спасибо,топ 1 уже поставил

Answer (score 0):

в mysql можно не объявлять переменную, а сразу воспользоваться ей

```
  set @m = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM db.table WHERE status=0);
  UPDATE db.table SET status=1 WHERE id= @m;
  select * from db.table ;
```